# Facebook API Javascript Not Defined

Tags: apache-flex, facebook-graph-api

This is a fairly general problem I am having here, so I figured I would ask, hopefully someone can help me out.

I have a flex app using the facebook js bridge to log in, and I am trying to pass the users name back to the app, but I am coming across the thing that I will explain after the code:

```
function getFriends() {
            var nameOfPlayer = "";
            FB.api('/me', function(response) {
                nameOfPlayer = response.name;
                });
            return nameOfPlayer;
        }
```

If I have my flex app print nameOfPlayer, it returns undefined, same as if I do an alert with nameOfPlayer, but if I do an alert inside of the FB.api call for nameOfPlayer, then it will pop up with my name, but it still won't return name. I tried having it return a general string, and that works, so it is passing the information over, it just isn't saving to the variable. Any idea how to fix this? This is probably very convoluted, so if I need to clarify anything let me know. Thanks in advance for any help you can give me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be doing this in an event-driven way.  Some pseudo-code is written below to get you started.

```
var yourFacebookAPIClass = new yourFacebookAPIClass();
yourFacebookAPIClass.addEventListener(Event.UserCallComplete, function(ev){
    var nameOfPlayer = SomeParser.ParseData(ev);
    someFunctionThatUsesYourVar(nameOfPlayer);
});
yourFacebookAPIClass.getNameOfPlayer();
```

---

In your facebook api class:

```
function getNameOfPlayer(){
    makeTheApiCallHere();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The function you're defining inside of the FB.api call is actually a callback function which means it's called asynchronously. So the line of code after the api call (the return statement) will execute right away without waiting for Facebook to return a response. The callback function, on the other hand, will wait for Facebook to response, in fact that's what it's designed for. You'd be better off doing all your logic that depends on the nameOfPlayer inside of that callback function.

If you definitely have to return a nameOfPlayer variable the way it's written you'd need to tell your code to wait for nameOfPlayer to be defined:

```
function getFriends() {
            var nameOfPlayer = "";
            FB.api('/me', function(response) {
                nameOfPlayer = response.name;
                });
            while(typeof nameOfPlayer === "undefined" || nameOfPlayer == "") {}
            return nameOfPlayer;
        }
```

But I really would not recommend this because your app will freeze while it waits for a response. You'd be better off doing everything inside of your callback function instead of returning something.

Good luck! :)

Comment: Thanks, thats what I thought was going on, because I saw that somewhere else, but I didn't know how to fix it, how would you suggest doing everything inside the callback, if you don't mind me asking?

Comment: Yes, the most reliable way to use the nameOfPlayer variable would be in the callback. If you don't want to stick too much logic in that function you could always pass the nameOfPlayer variable off to another function, but you would still need to call that function from within the callback in order to guarantee that it's defined correctly.